# Hover style attribute in html

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to add color to the text. I have more texts. So I retrieve the text color from the server and added the text color to the corresponding text. I want to add the border for the text and need to assign corresponding text color for the border when hovering the text.

In style sheet, we can able to give hover like below:

`.text: hover{
   color:#FF0000;
}`

But I have dynamic text color. I want to assign corresponding text color for the border for the corresponding text. In the style sheet, we cannot do.

Is there any way to add hover in style attribute in div?

Comment: You can't define pseudo-classes in the `style` attribute, unfortunately. You probably need to use JS for that.

Comment: You can create a class dynamically which hold the `color` and `border` property , add the class to you element on hover and delete the class on hover out.

Answer (score -1):

You're giving the space before **hover** and after the **colon(:)**, you have to write like this.

```
.text:hover {
  color:#FF0000;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you may achieve this using Jquery in my snippet I used common variable for color and utilised it please have a look.

Get hover event and add styles and remove styles dynamically

```js
var color = "red";
$(".mycontent").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css({
    "color": color,
    "border":" 1px solid "+color
    })
  },
  function () {
    $(this).css({
    "color": "inherit",
    "border":"inherit"
    })
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mycontent">  inner content</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I  hope this is helpful

```
div:hover .text:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

 div:hover .text:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}
```